# Hibernate 5.x migration suggestions script

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to convert my working (with Hibernate 4.x) script that suggests migrations from the actual database. This is convenient expecially when I want track changes and store them in sql script used from FlyWay.

This is my class:

```
public class SchemaGenerator {

private static Configuration cfg;
private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?tinyInt1isBit=false";
private static String username = "root";
private static String password = "password";

public SchemaGenerator(String packageName) throws Exception {
    cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driver);
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.test");
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
    for (Class c : allClasses) {
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(c);
    }

}

public static void validate() {
    SchemaValidator schemaValidator = new SchemaValidator(cfg);
    schemaValidator.validate();
}

public List<SchemaUpdateScript> createUpdateScript(DataSource dataSource, org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect dialect)
        throws SQLException {
    DatabaseMetadata meta = new DatabaseMetadata(dataSource.getConnection(), dialect, cfg);
    List<SchemaUpdateScript> createSQL = cfg.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList(dialect, meta);

    return createSQL;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SchemaGenerator gen = new SchemaGenerator("com.test");
    Driver driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.newInstance();
    DataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource(driver, url, username, password);

    List<SchemaUpdateScript> updateCommands = gen.createUpdateScript(dataSource,
            new org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect());
    if (updateCommands.size() != 0)
        System.out.println("" + formatSqlSuggestionScript(updateCommands));
    else
        System.out.println("Already up to date");
}

private static String formatSqlSuggestionScript(List<SchemaUpdateScript> sqls) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("\n\n****update sql suggestion:***\n\n");
    for (SchemaUpdateScript str : sqls) {
        builder.append("\n" + str.getScript() + ";");
    }
    builder.append("\n\n");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

I've some problems with `schemaValidator.validate();` because now it expects Metadata and with `cfg.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList(dialect, meta)` that doesn't exist anymore.

Do you have some good hints to start with? Or maybe is there a better approach to do this now with Hibernate 5x?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate `org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl` and use the [SchemaValidator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/SchemaValidator.html).